# How to exclude two sheets from the calcs when pressing F9 and having a button to calculate these two sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large workbook and I am trying to lighten the calcs when pressing F9 as it takes almost 1.30min.
Hence, I would like to deactivate the calculations of two heavy sheets and to have a macro that runs the formulas only when needed.

I have this code so far (1 for each sheet):

```
Sub OneTimeOnlyCalc()

Sheets("Sheet1").EnableCalculation = True

Sheets("Sheet1").EnableCalculation = False

End Sub
```

The problem is when I press F9, the calcs freeze at 14% as if these two sheets were blocking the rest of the calcs.

Have you ever tried something like this? What would you recommend to work around this?

Comment: The only way I see is to put a button to calculate only the desired sheets (`Worksheets("SheetToCalc").Calculate`) instead of pressing F9.

Comment: Thanks, @Pᴇʜ but I would like to keep the possibility to press F9... but I am taking your point in case this is not possible

Comment: When using Shift+F9 you only calculate the current Worksheet you are on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the next code to disable `F8` key function and allocate to it another procedure (in `ThisWorkbook` module):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
  Application.OnKey "{F9}", "SpecialCalculation"
End Sub
```

You can solve in the same way `Shift + F9`, `Ctrl + Alt + F9` (`"{+F9}"`), allocating them the same below procedure, `"^%F9}"`...

Then create your own Calculation function:

```
Sub SpecialCalculation()
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  For Each sh In Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> "sheet1 to be excluded name" And _
               sh.Name <> "sheet2 to be excluded name" Then
            sh.Calculate
        End If
 Next
End Sub
```

If you need to reverse to the default behavior, use this piece of code in the `Deactivate` workbook event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.OnKey "{F9}"
End Sub
```

Edited: Changed the events to be used following the discussion with @PEH. He was right. It is better to keep this special behavior of Calculation function only for the workbook keeping these specific events, configured as suggested.

Comment: @Antoine If you use this solution, make sure that you document it well. Changing the default behaviour of Excel otherwise can drive people using your workook insane. I recommend something like on the first press on F9 put a message box that wars the user about the changed behavior. Use a global variable to remember it is the first time you press F9.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: The code can also be used in the `Activate` workbook event and reverse to its standard behavior on `Deactivate` event. Anyhow, the default behavior is obtained at `BeforeClose` event...

Comment: Yes, I meant if not only the OP uses this file but also co-workers, then changing a default behavior must be documented very well, or you will quickly find out how much people can hate you. • Actually your soultion is good but I highly recommend to use `Activate` and `Deactivate` events instead of `Workbook_Open` otherwise this will affect all workbooks in the current Excel instance as `.OnKey` applies to the whole `Application` and not to `Workbook` object. It has high potential to cause issues like it is in your original answer. Anyway you got my upvote.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: You are right! I will also adapt the answer in order to make it using of `Activate`/`Deactivate` events...